# re.sub with brackets, removing Japanese ruby characters

Tags: python, regex

How can I change

`a = "[ruby(空,ruby=そら)]は[ruby(青,ruby=あお)]い。"`

into

`"空は青い。"`?

I tried

`re.sub(r"\[ruby\(.,ruby=.\)\]",".",a)`

but not working at all.

Comment: Try with `.*` or `.+`

Comment: Now that returns `".い。"`.

Comment: Did you replace all the `.`?

Comment: I tried `re.sub(r"\[ruby\(.*,ruby=.*\)\]",".",a)`

Comment: Ok forget my previous comment try this: `re.sub(r"[\[\]\(\)=A-z]","",a)`

Comment: The result is `'空そらは青あおい。'` and that doesn't remove Japanese characters after `"ruby="`(which are`"そら"` and  `"あお"`).

Comment: This one is the good one I think: `\[ruby\(|,ruby=[^\)]+|[\)\]]`.

By the way, I use this site to test my regex (there is a Python mode): https://regex101.com/

Comment: Now it works. Thanks for the site

Comment: You have 2 ways to achieve what you want, replacing what do not belong to the final string by nothing, or tracking the string you want to keep (and both can be done thanks to regexp) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
a = re.sub(r'\[ruby\(([^(),]*),[^()]*\)]', r'\1', a)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sqGtg2/1/). Details:

- `\[ruby\(` - a `[ruby(` text
- `([^(),]*)` - Group 1: any text other than `(`, `)` and a comma, zero or more occurrences
- `,`  - a comma
- `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)]`  -  a `)]` text.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/JLG9VI):

```py
import re
a = "[ruby(空,ruby=そら)]は[ruby(青,ruby=あお)]い。"
print( re.sub(r'\[ruby\(([^(),]*),[^()]*\)]', r'\1', a) )
# => 空は青い。
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
a = "[ruby(空,ruby=そら)]は[ruby(青,ruby=あお)]い。"
desired="空は青い。"
```

You can use alteration to remove the sub strings:

```
>>> s=re.sub(r'\[ruby\(|,ruby=[^)]+\)\]','',a)
>>> s
空は青い。
>>> s==desired
True
```